# Parameter is string but still getting this warning: Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to update my mysql database of username however, whenever my username contains any numbers (despite being overall a string), it will still output
Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in

I've tried to use it without prepare and bind param, which works.

```php
function setUsername($guid, $username2) {
        global $serverName, $username, $password, $database;
        $conn = new mysqli($serverName, $username, $password, $database);
        $username2 = $username2 . "";
        $query = $conn->prepare("UPDATE players SET username = ? WHERE guid = ?");
        $query->bind_param("si", $username2, $guid);
        $conn->query($query);
    }
```

I expected this to update successfully. However, if I include any numbers within the string, such as
awefw1afweaw, it will output Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `$conn->query()` with a prepared statement. [`$conn->prepare()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) returns a [`mysqli_stmt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) object, that you are passing to `$conn->query(mysqli_stmt)`, and is the cause of your error message.

Instead you would need to replace `$conn->query()` with [`$query->execute();`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)

```
function setUsername($guid, $username2) {
    global $serverName, $username, $password, $database;
    $conn = new mysqli($serverName, $username, $password, $database);
    $username2 = $username2 . "";
    $query = $conn->prepare("UPDATE players SET username = ? WHERE guid = ?");
    $query->bind_param("si", $username2, $guid);
    $query->execute();
}
```